# Push messages on Google Pub/Sub with authentication without SDK

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-authentication

I'm developing a google-cloud-platform client via REST API to publish messages on Google cloud Pub/Sub. I'm having some troubles with authentication.

```
get permission denied error
```

If I do it with google sdk everything works. There's a process to authenticate without using google sdk?

thanks a lot

Comment: Where this error occurs? On your local environment? Where will you deploy your REST API?

Comment: Your question needs a lot of details. Start with which type of authentication you are trying to implement, then post your code with error messages.

Comment: Sorry for lack o details. Anyway I've resolved the trouble, I've used an API key defined in GCP credentials section and I've used it in the header of REST request to perform the authentication. Thanks anyway